# An alternative to getElementsByTagName and pass information

Tags: javascript, html

I've been looking to find an alternative to getElementsByTagName for something that requires a valid HTML format. I don't really want to use a form to pass the information. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<div style="padding: 5px 10px 5px;"><my-widget myId="3053" myOtherId="hello"></my-widget></div>




<script>
let e = document.getElementsByTagName("my-widget");
                0 == e.length && (e = document.getElementsByClassName("my-widget"));
                for (let t = 0; t < e.length; t++) {
                    let n = e.item(t),
                        r = this.defaultOptions;
                    Object.keys(this.defaultOptions).forEach(e => {
                        let t = n.attributes.getNamedItem(e);
                        if (null != t) switch (t.name.toLowerCase()) {
                            case "mytype":
                                {
                                    let n = this.getValidTypes(t.value);
                                    null != n && (r[e] = n);
                                    break
                                }
                            case "myothertype":
                                {
                                    let n = this.getValidOtherTypes(t.value);
                                    null != n && (r[e] = n);
                                    break
                                }
                            default:
                                r[e] = t.value
                        }
                    }), this.createWidget(n, r)
                }


</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, please can you be more specific? You haven't given enough details or context. What exactly do you want to send, and where? How is getElementsByTagName related to this? And what's the problem with using a form? And what's the status / relevance of the code above - is it designed to do something specific, and is there an issue with it which you'd like us to look into?

Comment: get element by class or id? Latter will be unique to whole page. Former will be according to CSS styling rules. Can be applied on multiple tag types.

Comment: The above code is used for a widget and it grabs the values from the tag name and passes in a variable to be used. Just seeing for an alternative way. Wasn’t sure how to use getElementById to pass multiple values into a js variable.

Comment: "Just seeing for an alternative way"...ok, because? What's the problem, exactly? We can't easily suggest an alternative unless we understand what the current difficulty is.

Comment: The widget is being stripped by a companies custom Wordpress because they want valid html and not some custom tags.

Comment: Ok. So how can we help you with that? It's still unclear what you want to do instead, or how it relates to your code.  We are not mind-readers, remember, and we are not familiar with your application or widgets

Comment: There are many ways to get an element... By id, class, or any other tag attribute (maybe a data-Attribute) via onload passing the component to the function. I have no clue how this is usually handled for WordPress but generating a (unique) id is probably the best way.